# NetBeans 7.0 Randomly delete files from server on 'Download' command

Tags: file, netbeans, random, delete-file

1. I add a new PHP Project from Remote Server
2. I download the source files to my PC
3. When Netbeans downloads the files, it randomly deletes files from server.

Why does this happen?

My configuration is:

```
Netbeans 7.0, default configurations. 
Remote Sever via SSH. (sftp)
```

Answer (score 4):

This issue has been logged, reproduced and apparently fixed for 7.1 target.

http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=202673

In the meantime, after each full download of your site, do a Find inside the Remote Log console window for the `DELE` (match case, whole word) command. This will identify for you which files were deleted and you can re upload them.

If that's too tedious and you have time for a coffee break, simply re-upload your entire directory after downloading it.

It seems to have to do with the Upload On Save feature, so if you turn that off, presumably the issue should go away as well.

You can grab the latest nightly and the issue should also be resolved, according to the primary committer.

Comment: I just realized this is happening to me in Netbeans 7.1 for Windows 7.  I am sure of it because I found the `DELE` lines in the remote server output.  How could this be?  I am pretty sure I have had it happen with Netbeans 7.1.2 for Ubuntu also.